# change structure of an object javascript

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, node.js

I want to change the structure of an object javascript, for example:

I have this structure :

```
obj = {
        "email": "abc@site.com", 
        "societe.name": "xyz"
      }
```

and I want to change it to :

```
obj = {
        "email": "abc@site.com",
        "societe": {
            "name": "xyz"
        }
      }
```

thank's for help.

Comment: this doesn't tell us anything about how it is implemented, or why you can't just change it to what you show. nor does it show any research effort.

Comment: `obj[societe] = {};``obj[societe][name] = obj["societe.name"];` `delete obj["societe.name"];`

Comment: It's pretty obvious what requirement the example is illustrating. There's no need to berate OP for not putting it into words.

Comment: yes you can change it

Comment: @BatScream I want to thank you a lot, thank's a lot man, it's been three days since I tried without any result. thank you

Comment: @dbyba You are most welcome. Happy learning ;-)

Comment: @tophallen sorry if I have not explained well, and if I ask here that's because I didn't find the solution, I spent three days withot Any result. thank you and thank to BatScream

Comment: @BatScream i am deleting my ans

Comment: @NasirMahmood - You could have improved it. The question was `how` to change the structure. i think you misunderstood it, that's why had to point it out. No offense ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var obj = {
    "email": "abc@site.com",
        "societe.name": "xyz"
};

var newObj = {};
var keys = Object.keys(obj);

for (var i = 0; i < keys.length ; i++) {
    var key = keys[i];

    // you can change this to '.name' if you want to be specific      
    if (key.indexOf('.') > -1) {
        var splitted = key.split('.');
        var innerObj = {};
        innerObj[splitted[1]] = obj[key];
        newObj[splitted[0]] = innerObj;
    } else {
        newObj[key] = obj[key];
    }
}

console.log(newObj);
```

[`JSFIDDLE`](http://jsfiddle.net/2Lgsz3tv/).